# postgres backup for specific table with blob oid

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, blob, pg-dump

I have a table which has an oid column. When I'm taking a backup of this table, it takes complete oids (complete blob / oids backup). But my table only has 10 entries (which is approximately 30 entries in pg_largeobject table). I read the following link and added *-o* and *-b* to the backup parameters.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html

I am using below command to take backup.

```
 pg_dump -i -h myhost -p 5432 -U myuser -F c -v -t schema.my_table -o -b -f mytablebkp.backup "mydb"
```

Is anything wrong with that command? How can I take a backup of only the specific table with only those blobs that belong to it?

Update:

I read the following from documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgrestore.html),

*pg_restore cannot restore large objects selectively; for instance, only those for a specific table. If an archive contains large objects, then all large objects will be restored, or none of them if they are excluded via -L, -t, or other options*

Since pg_restore can not do selective restore, is there no way / possibility to take selective table backups with blob / oid ?

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried to `pg_dump` **without** the `-b` option? I would think that this would dump the whole table anyway.

Comment: @ypercube, I have tried with / without -b option; with b, its taking complete backup of large objects (where my specific table is having only few entries), without b, its taking backup as flat data as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `oid` column are avaliable in all tables, and I believe thats not a issue.

To create a logical dump of this table, you just need add a option `-b` (or `--blobs` in the `pg_dump` arguments, eg:

```
pg_dump \
  -U user\
  -t table_name \
  --blobs \
  -f dump_file_name \
  database_name
```

Another options will be useful is the `-F c` (or `--format=custom`) to change the default format from `plain` to `custom`.

Please take a look at the documentation for more details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: i am not clear with first point. Is all tables having oid by default even table script not having any oid datatypes?. And -b takes complete blob backup (not only the mentioned table's oids).

Comment: _'The oid column are avaliable in all tables'_ - well, that's not true unless you create your tables with `WITH OIDS`.  At least not true in recent (last 15 years or so ;) versions.  Also, the OP has all these options in there command already, so what does your answer add  that they don't already know?